# Where is the file of the *beep* noise in batch?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a batch file with this line of code in it:

```
choice /c:123 /n
```

This is basically a glorified `pause` that only proceeds if 1, 2, or 3 have been pressed.  If I press any other button, It will beep.  I've search around the internet for the file location of this beep, but I can't find anything.

Where is the file located?  How can I get access this sound file?

Comment: There is no sound file. It calls [`Beep`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/ms679277), which will happily generate the sound at runtime (which, on Windows 10 at least, produces a nice pure sine wave). So if you're looking to customize it: you can't, barring some nasty import patching. On the plus side, since it actually goes to the sound card on modern systems (instead of being delegated to the archaic PC speaker) it respects volume controls.

Comment: The Windows console (conhost.exe) also used to `Beep` when displaying ^G (0x07), but nowadays it calls `PlaySound` to play the SystemHand (Critical Stop) sound. I prefer a simple sinusoidal beep, but not for a critical stop. It would have been better to add a ConsoleBeep event.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Choice.exe imports the [`Beep`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679277(v=vs.85).aspx) function and that is where the sound comes from, it is not a wav file on disk, it is generated dynamically. You can run it in a debugger and set a breakpoint on that function to figure out the exact parameters it is using. On Windows 10 it uses (1500, 500).

Comment: I didn't go this far, but I imported `Beep` in a PowerShell session. Experimentally, it sounds exactly like `Beep(1500, 500)`.

Comment: @JeroenMostert I just debugged it and you are 100% correct, great guess.

Comment: Guess? Careful comparative acoustics, you mean. (Also, the machine I'm on has no development tools, so my options were limited. :-))

Answer (score 1):

You can get the beep sound using a little trick with the FORFILES command as documented on [DosTips.com](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=3857)

```
@echo off
setlocal

::Define a Linefeed variable
set LF=^


::above 2 blank lines are critical - do not remove.

call :hexprint "0x07" rtnvar

FOR /L %%L IN (1,1,5) do echo %rtnvar%
pause
exit /b

:hexPrint  string  [rtnVar]
  for /f eol^=^%LF%%LF%^ delims^= %%A in (
    'forfiles /p "%~dp0." /m "%~nx0" /c "cmd /c echo(%~1"'
  ) do if "%~2" neq "" (set %~2=%%A) else echo(%%A
exit /b
```

Comment: This won't get you the specific beep sound produced by `choice`. If you did want the sound file for the beep produced by echoing the BEL character, it's the sound configured in System Sound as "Default Beep", so just look there. If you just want the beep to *sound* (which was not the question, even if this was the right beep), this seems absurdly overcomplicated. `echo ^G` suffices, where `^G` is the character you get by pressing Ctrl-G. You can get this character into a file even from the command prompt: `copy con: beep.bat`, `echo ^G`;`<enter>`;`^Z`. `call beep.bat` as desired.

Comment: @JeroenMostert, then post your code as an answer instead of lambasting mine.  I was just giving another alternative.  Didn't need a dissertation from you nor is my answer wrong in anyway.